# Kali Linux error while seeting up VM

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux

I'm currently setting up my learner lab for learn some basics of IT forensics and pentesting, and during the setup of the VM (using Oracle's VirtualBox) an error occured;

[image]

So I created a syslog file via the menu, which gave this output:

[image]

Unfortunately my experive with linux is limited, but I'm wonderung about the last line; No space left, as there's plenty space.

I hope you can give me a usefull advice here (but not "Stop using Kali").

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How much RAM and hdd space have you allocated for this VM?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove 20 GB HDD 2 GB RAM

Comment: Sounds good, what's your system architecture? 32 or 64 bit? And the image you're trying to install?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove 64 Bit, offical Kali image, checksum verified

Comment: Hm everything sounds in order. Have you tried deleting the virtual hdd and vm box and redoing it?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove 3rd Attempt now, also tried 4 GB RAM

Comment: And what did you set as the type of OS?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Linux 2.6/3.x/4.x 64 Bit

Comment: Set it to Debian x64 and give it a try, if you can't find this we might need to change a virtualization setting in BIOS.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove I'll try this asap

Comment: how goes the install?

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Sorry for the late answer; I worked with the Debian workaround

Comment: no worries, glad we got it figured out. :)

Comment: Please accept my answer so that it will easily be seen on how to solve this issue instead of having to read through the comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the type of OS on the virtual machine to Debian x64(closest to Kali Linux x64) should work for you. If this is not an option you'll need to go into BIOS. virtualization settings. Set the Microsoft virtualization settings to enabled.

Comment: I am sure you can make this answer into something more then a single sentence.  *I was not reviewing the comments, I reviewed your answer, I really wish the system would allow me to simply review content without submitting comments on my behalf.*  The only alternative is not selecting a reason which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. I will add a bit more technical explanation as to the reason why this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to install Kali 2016.1 on VMware Workstation Player from the 2016.1 ISO.

If you have not tried already, Kali has pre-made virtual's for VMware, VirtualBox, and Hyper-V.

Try downloading the VirtualBox image, and then import Kali as an existing image in VirtualBox.

[Kali VirtualBox Downloads](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/)